# How do you display two content on a view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

in my `master.blade.php` i have this code

```
@include('layouts.top-header')

<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGIN STYLES -->
    @yield('usercss')    
<!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGIN STYLES -->

@include('layouts.header')    
@include('layouts.top-navigation')    
@include('layouts.sidebar') 

    @yield('content')

@include('layouts.footer')
```

and this does not work when I run it in the browser
and when I call it in my page

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('usercss')
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blahhh.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="blahblah.css"/>
@stop

@section('content')
  some content
@stop
```

Comment: your layout is called `masters`, but when you extend it you use `master`.

Comment: edited it already.. just typo

Comment: What do you mean by, `does not work`? You may have to elaborate.

Comment: `this does not work` ? What it means ? What happens ?

Comment: its working now.. my css just messed up..

Comment: Check my answer, that's the right way :-)

Answer (score 0):

use this instead (Make sure your `css` file inside `public/css` folder):

```
{{ HTML::style('css/blahhh.css') }}
```

Also you may use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/blahhh.css') }}" type="text/css">
```

**Extra**: You may use `HTML::script('url')` to include scripts.